# Android Auto-Populate Key, values In TextBox Like Search Engine

Tags: android

1. I'm Doing a small android app.
2. I'm very new to android.
3. Here my question is I have a Layout with two editable text box.
4. In first box instead of typing complete word if I type 'c' It should suggest words related to 'c' like color.
5. In the corresponding next box if I type 'B' It should suggest colors starts with 'B' like Blue, Black.
6. Can Anyone Teach me how to do this.
7. I'm very Thankful for this.

Comment: use AutoCompleteTextView for this

Comment: you can follow these links for help http://www.materialdoc.com/autocomplete-view/                                                                                                         http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-add-autocompletion-to-an-edittext

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for multiple world you have need to use the ***MultiAutoCompleteView***
put below code in Layout file.

```
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
      android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="10"
      android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
      android:hint="Multi Auto Complete " />
```

in Java file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   MultiAutoCompleteTextView text2;
  String[] color={"Blue","Black","some color","some color","some color","some color"};



   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      text2=(MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);

      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,color);


      text2.setAdapter(adapter);
      text2.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks boss it's working...and one more thing in first text view if I choose color then it should give drop downs in second text view related to the color(black,blue....).

Comment: If I select Brand in first text view then it should suggest only brands not colors. Once again thanks a lot@ak sacha

Answer (score 0):

please use two ***AutoCompleteTextView*** instead of EditText.
in Layout file put below code between Vertical LinearLayout or as per your need.

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
               android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
               android:ems="10" >
    <AutoCompleteTextView
               android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView2"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
               android:ems="10" >
```

in java file put below code

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

           AutoCompleteTextView text,text1;

           String[] str={"Color","some text","some text","some text","some text","some text"};
String[] color={"Blue","Black","some color","some color","some color","some color"};

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              text=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
  text1=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);


              ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,str);
  ArrayAdapter colorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,color);

              text.setAdapter(adapter);
              text.setThreshold(1);

text1.setAdapter(colorAdapter);
              text1.setThreshold(1);


           }
    }
```

Comment: One more help from you boss@ak sacha

Comment: I want to validate the first text view that is should not allow the user to enter more than one word.Where as in second text view the user may allow to enter any number of words separated by ,

Comment: android:maxlength and android:maxlines will solve the my problem to limit the first text view and using hash map as a key value pair color and related colors.

Comment: Thanks for your support@ak sacha